# Are there any way to list all installed package with `apt-get` that I explicitly typed?

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to list all packages I have installed with `apt-get` but only packages that I explicitly type with the command.

For example, with `sudo apt list` it will list all packages that I have no idea I ever installed. I think it was installed as dependencies to other packages. I don't want this. I only want those packages that I have ever directly typed in the terminal.

How can I get the list?

Comment: `apt-mark showmanual` will show all packages marked as manually installed whether installed by you or as the base system. ie  it does not show auto-installed packages.

Comment: It still shows many `unity` and `xserver` packages I never installed manually.

Comment: those were installed by the installer (your base install) they are marked as manually installed. not sure if possible to get only the ones you installed

Comment: :( okay it is still hundreds packages I need to manually sort.

Comment: this might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3624/240475